# How come the nav bar on stackoverflow.com jumps when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Nice new nav bar on stackoverflow. Looks like the bootstrap I am using. It has the same problem that my site does, the nav bar jumps slightly when clicked.

Any ideas how to fix it? I haven't looked too close, but I'm thinking there should be some sort of javascript fix to hold the screen until it repaints.

Comment: This questions seems like it's in limbo. Sorta feels like it might be better on Meta.SO as a bug report. Might even get the answer to how to fix your site too.

Comment: When I click it it seems that the scrollbar disappears for a moment and the navbar moves into that space, then the scrollbar comes back so the navbar moves back. Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: Click on the SO icon on the far left. When the screen reloads, the nav bar will jump slightly, about 5 pixels maybe, from left to right.

Comment: The site is presumably using Javascript to rearrange things. This happens after the HTML is loaded, so first you see the original HTML, then you see the rearranged display.

Comment: @Barmar I think you are right, but it looks stupid. Can JS fix it?

Comment: This question definitely belongs on the meta site. Unless you're the SO programmer, and you're asking for advice on how to fix what you've done.

Comment: Why so, isn't it a question about getting Bootstrap to work well?

Comment: It's really a bug report to the SO programmers, they need to figure out how to do it right.

Comment: It's not a proper SO question, because you haven't posted any of the Bootstrap code that needs to be fixed.

Comment: fair enough -- don't know if I can "move" a question.

Comment: You can flag it for the moderators to move.

Comment: It doesn't belong on Meta. I know the answer. It will take me a few minutes to properly formulate.And for all those who said the opposite, it's a proper question. It's all CSS. Maybe it could have been better formulated and researched, but for me it's perfectly valid.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Thanks, I agree and look forward to your answer. I'll remove flag. I'll be happy to edit the question if I understand the answer better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the navbar *jumps* is because at load time the browser calculates, based on the information it has about the content, that it won't need a scrollbar. Therefore it starts rendering using full viewport width. For a quick flash, until enough of the page has loaded to make the browser paint the scrollbar, the navbar is *full-width*.

That means, in desktop browsers, it is `17px` wider than on pages with scrollbar.

**Note:** Before trying to fix this, please note it's only an issue on wide, pointer based devices. It doesn't exist on ***mobile/touch devices***. Any method from below should be limited, using media queries or device detection, to desktop, pointer based devices.

A few methods on dealing with this:

- give certain elements `min-height` property so that the browser will estimate the initial height of the page correctly (or at least more accurate).
- give `<body>` a min-height of `calc(100vh + 1px)` on pages you are certain will have a scrollbar.
- use `overflow:scroll` on `<body>` on pages that you know know will have scrollbar (always wrap this in a media query)
- hide (as in: `opacity:0`) all *above the fold* content and fade it in when a particular element has loaded (typically used on `window` load event, but you could just use a particular HTML element for this, if the page is very long and you don't care about the bottom parts to be loaded when you paint the top) - this technique is widely used by AngularJs websites/apps, principle from `ng-cloak` directive, but with `opacity`. Effective at removing FOUC and this desktop scrollbar jump issue.
- use a scrollbar plugin, removing the default scrollbar. Custom scrollbars are usually positioned absolute, over the content and don't influence content rendering.
- (this is more of a hack, but I use it):

```css
@media (min-width: $md-min) {      /* 768px ?  */
 #navbar {          /* assuming this is navbar */
   position:absolute;
   left: 0; top: 0;       /* depends on layout */
   min-width: 100vw;
 }
 body {
   margin-top: 60px; /* navbar height @desktop */
   overflow-x: hidden;
 }
}
```

**Note:** This issue is also known as *the modal overlay navigation bug*, because when modals give body `position:fixed` in order to place the overlay, the navigation jumps to full width (as the body no longer has a scrollbar). It's a long discussion, with various fixes. [`example`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9855).

---

From my point of view, this is a fault of desktop browser developers.
Sidebar should never, ever, interfere with window width calculation. You either paint it over the content (only when the user scrolls?) or you paint it aside from the page in a manner that still looks good when you don't have a scrollbar.
It's not that hard.

Comment: In this case the header is always displayed as part of the "template" of the website. Does that change or promote any of your recommendations? You'll also notice the nav bar (on this site anyway) is fixed, the site scrolls under it.

Comment: It really depends on the use-case. Let's talk about your website, not about SO and I'll be able to provide a few methods. Could you create a [mcve]?

Comment: Well, an example needs a website, so a minimal-complete-verifiable is kinda too much to post. Let me think about it a sec.

Comment: Not really, you can just create a `jsFiddle` and put dummy data in it. Take your time. As for solution, depending on website, I deal with this by going `position: absolute;min-width: 100vw;` on navbar and `margin-top: {navbar height};overflow-x:hidden;` on body. Or by using a custom scrollbar plugin.